# How to return the caller of setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclick, tablerow

I have an array of TableRow, for each of them I've set a OnClickListener. I want to know which TableRow in the tr_o array is called when it's clicked?

```
 tr_o[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){                             
                        @Override  
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent();  
                            intent.setClass(a.this, b.class);  
                            startActivity(intent);  

                        }  
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID of the current view to your intent:

```
                @Override  
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();  
                        intent.setClass(a.this, b.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ViewId", v.getId();  
                        startActivity(intent);  

                    }
```

Then in your receiving class you know which view started it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr_o[j].getId()` (or) `tr_o[j].getTag()` for this purpose.

Assuming you are setting Id for each table row while constructing table.